# Kafka rack config in bitnami docker image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, bitnami

Is this any way to configure rack id in bitnami kafka image without changing it manually in config file while container run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the server.properties file while the broker is running.

You should be able to use an environment variable like all the other settings

`KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_RACK`

Comment: tnx , but unfortunately there is no such configuration value.
I think I will override this docker image and add logic that we need.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. All server properties are able to be set by `KAFKA_CFG_(property)`. You don't need to override anything. Read bottom of this section https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka#configuration

Comment: The maintainers of that image are fairly responsive if you are sure it doesn't work https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/issues

Comment: wow I missed that KAFKA_CFG_ works for all props , tnx

Comment: @OneCricketeer 's link now 404s, it should be https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/kafka#configuration . You can still set `KAFKA_CFG_*` as they described